# Play wav sound when click to button in wpf

Tags: wpf

i want to play sound with click event of my button click event in my whole applciation,

i found 1 code that play sound when i click the button.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaPlayer mplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mplayer.Open(new Uri("ding.wav", UriKind.Relative));
        mplayer.Play();
        //our code...
    }
```

i know this is not right solution, so please tell me if there are other solution, becoz i have to write this 3 line to each and every button click event and its tedious job.

please help to solve this problem.

waiting for reply...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just define a style that plays the sound on the event `PreviewMouseDown`:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
            <SoundPlayerAction Source="/ClickingButton;component/click.wav" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

See [here](http://www.e-tobi.net/blog/2009/07/20/wpf-howto-1-making-your-buttons-beep) for a discussion on why not to use `Button.Click` event in the event trigger. Basically, the problem is, that the `Button.Click` event is a bubbling one and the event trigger will be executed *after*  the code in your normal click handler executed, i.e. the sound will have a delay, if your event handler does something that takes some time.

Comment: i get error while i put this code between <windoe.Recources> tag. "Could not load file or assembly 'ClickingButton, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. "

Comment: Sure. You need to change it to your needs... See the remarks in the MSDN for this property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.soundplayeraction.source.aspx