# WPF delayed sound when click button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and XAML (like really new), and I am trying to make a UI for a app I am doing for fun. I have an issue when I am trying to give sound to a clicked button. The sound is always delayed.

Now I saw a few topics about it already ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962982/play-wav-sound-when-click-to-button-in-wpf)) but there was still a delay (maybe I did it wrong, but I am pretty sure I did it right).

I also tried to do it with Click event or with PreviewMouseDown but nothing changed (here is the PreviewMouseDown code I tried):

```
private void RegisterButton_Copy_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        DependencyObject originalSource = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
        var button = originalSource as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase;

        while (button == null && originalSource != null)
        {
            originalSource = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(originalSource);
            button = originalSource as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase;
        }

        if (button != null)
        {
            new SoundPlayerAction(@"Sound.wav").Play();
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is Wav file located(maybe need full path)? What is the size?  What type of drive on machine (solid state)?

Comment: The wav file located fine, I am using the full path but I changed it here because the path isnt relevant. Plus, you hear the wanted sound after clicking the button, but in delay. How can I find the type of drive on machine?

Comment: How much delay are we talking about here?

Comment: You could always preload the wav into memory so you didn't have the slowness of the disk read making the delay.

Comment: @Wyck like one second, maybe little less, its noticeable

Comment: @KevinCook hmm intersting, how do you do that?

Comment: Set the file as a resource aka:  StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Sounds/Pop.WAV", UriKind.Relative)); and then use SoundPlayer(sri.Stream); sp.Play(); to run it.

Comment: Here is a link to help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145209/how-to-play-a-wpf-sound-file-resource

Comment: I don't see a constructor for `SoundPlayerAction` that takes a string argument.  How are you running that code?  Which version?  Regardless, I would expect that surprising the system by telling it the filename and then immediately expecting it to play that file will have poor latency (because loading the file will take time).  But constructing a SoundPlayer *once* well in advance, and then just asking it to Play when the button clicks should perform way better in terms of latency.